# Submit a form when Bootstrap radio button clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a form with a radio-button group:

```
<form name="search" class="form-inline" asp-controller="controller" asp-action="action" method="get">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label onclick="document.search.submit()" class="btn btn-default @ActiveTime("AM")" onclick="document.search.submit()">
      <input type="radio" name="time" value="am" autocomplete="off">AM
    </label>
    <label onclick="document.search.submit()" class="btn btn-default @ActiveTime("PM")" onclick="document.search.submit()">
      <input type="radio" name="time" value="pm" autocomplete="off">PM
    </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

`@ActiveTime`:

```
public string ActiveTime(string time)
{
    if (ViewData["time"].ToString() == time) { return "active"; }
    return "";
}
```

Relevant section of `controller\action`:

```
string time = ( (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.Query["time"].ToString())) ? "am" : HttpContext.Request.Query["time"].ToString() ).ToUpper();
ViewData["time"] = time;
```

Clicking the AM or PM label will submit the form, but doesn't include the radio button's value.  What am I missing?

Comment: Show your action code.

Comment: Which checkbox value are you talking about ? The code you shared does not have a checkbox at all!

Comment: @Shyju, [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) calls it a Checkbox/Radio.

Answer (score 0):

It is not sending the value of the radio button because when user clicks on the label, the browsers javascript engine will execute the `onclick` event handler you wired up on that element. Your current handler will execute this code `document.search.submit()` which submits the form immediately, even before bootstrap library could adjust the radio button state.

You can solve the issue by hijacking the click handler and set the radio button value yourself and then submit the form (all in javascript).

Another option i would try is, to remove the form submit behavior from the radio button selection/click event. What if user want to change his selection ? I would create a separate "Submit" button for the form submission.

I also noticed you have `onclick` handler registered two times on your element. clean that up.